# Grafana alert when previous value increases

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I'm trying to create an alert rule in Grafana that fires when the value of a counter metric increases by 1 or more? So if the counter is showing 5 and then it increases to 6, I want an alert that will fire when this event change happens.

Currently I'm looking at

sum(increase(counter metric***[5m]))

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are on right track. Generally `increase(my_metric_total[1m]) > 0` should do what you want. Why do you feel the need to ask a question?

Comment: @markalex will that show what the new value that increase. Show if the counter increased from 5 to 6, can the alert show the new value? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: No, this will return the actual increase (with some some precision). If you want value to be returned, you need something like `my_metric_total and increase(my_metric_total[1m]) > 0` or maybe `my_metric_total > my_metric_total offset 1m`